# Let R be the relation on the set of real numbers defined by $(x,y) \in R$ if $x^2 \leq y^2$ then R is?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Ok, so I am trying to understand why this problem is not anti-symmetric. From my understanding if $x^2 \leq y^2$ and $y^2 \leq x^2$ implies $x = y$ then it is anti-symmetric. I can't think of a counter-example that would prove this not true.

Comment: What about $x=1$ and $y=-1$?

Comment: Ok. I see now, thank you. I must not have been thinking real numbers. So simple :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the solution was simple, thanks to the commenter. I must just have been tired and not thinking of real numbers. X= -2 y =2 is a counter example.